# setting a field in SQL with the product of other field values

Tags: sql, sql-server, ms-access

I am trying to change update a field with the product of 3 other fields while using an update control button in Visual studio on this table my code and table follow does anyone know the correct syntax
I am just now learning SQL for access`

```
 SELECT (student_Score1 + student_Score2 + student_Score3) / 3 AS student_Avg
     FROM     Student
  UPDATE Student
 SET         [ student_Grade] = 'A'
                  WHERE  [student_Avg] = '[90 100]';
   SET          [student_Grade] = 'B'
   WHERE  [student_Avg] = '[80 89]';
  SET          [student_Grade] = 'C'
   WHERE  [student_Avg] = '[70 79]';``
  SET          [student_Grade] = 'D'
  WHERE  [student_Avg] = '[60 69]';
  SET          [student_Grade] = 'F'
  WHERE  [student_Avg] = '[1 59]';
```

Comment: This question relates to `SQL SERVER` or `ACCESS`?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your scores are integers, the below should work:

```
UPDATE Student
set student_grade = 
case 
    when (student_Score1 + student_Score2 + student_Score3) / 3 between 90 and 100 then 'A'
    when (student_Score1 + student_Score2 + student_Score3) / 3 between 80 and  89 then 'B'
    when (student_Score1 + student_Score2 + student_Score3) / 3 between 70 and  79 then 'C'
    when (student_Score1 + student_Score2 + student_Score3) / 3 between 60 and  69 then 'D'
    when (student_Score1 + student_Score2 + student_Score3) / 3 between 50 and  59 then 'E'
    else 'F'
end
```

NB: If those columns weren't integers you could potentially find values such as 89.33 which would result in an F since it's not between 80 and 89 or between 90 and 100.  You could correct for that using the `FLOOR` function to round down to the nearest integer.

The below avoids the potential rounding issue and saves rewriting the calculation multiple times:

```
UPDATE Student
set student_grade = 
case floor((student_Score1 + student_Score2 + student_Score3) / 30)
    when 10 then 'A'
    when 9 then 'A'
    when 8 then 'B'
    when 7 then 'C'
    when 6 then 'D'
    when 5 then 'E'
    else 'F'
end
```

Or if you want to calculate the avg_score to its own column (potentially useful if you're going to be reusing that calculation again for other column updates), you could do something like this:

```
UPDATE s
set student_grade = 
case 
    when x.avg_score between 90 and 100 then 'A'
    when x.avg_score between 80 and  89 then 'B'
    when x.avg_score between 70 and  79 then 'C'
    when x.avg_score between 60 and  69 then 'D'
    when x.avg_score between 50 and  59 then 'E'
    else 'F'
end
from Student s
inner join 
(
    select id, FLOOR((student_Score1 + student_Score2 + student_Score3) / 3) avg_score
    from student
) x
on x.id = s.id
```

My personal preference is the second method for its brevity and maintainability, but choose the option which makes most sense to you, since you'll have to support & thus understand this code.

Answer (score 1):

```
UPDATE STUDENT
SET [student_Grade] = CASE WHEN [student_Avg] BETWEEN [90] AND [100] THEN 'A'
                           WHEN [student_Avg] BETWEEN [80] AND [89] THEN 'B'
                           WHEN [student_Avg] BETWEEN [70] AND [79] THEN 'C'
                           WHEN [student_Avg] BETWEEN [60] AND [69] THEN 'D'
                           WHEN [student_Avg] BETWEEN [1] AND [59] THEN 'F'
                      END;
```

Comment: No problem it would be best to add a column that calculates the student_Avg before you run this update statement depending on how big the table is. I thought you already had a column name that's why I didn't provide any calculations or anything.

Answer (score 0):

Although not clear without the schema, I think you're trying to check if avg falls in a range in which case the correct syntax for SQL Server is this `... WHERE  [student_Avg] BETWEEN 60 AND 69;`

If `student_Avg` is not a field then you can combine both in one:

```
... WHERE  ((student_Score1 + student_Score2 + student_Score3) / 3) BETWEEN 60 AND 69;
```

Furthermore, you need to combine all different cases using... a `CASE`:

```
UPDATE Student
SET [ student_Grade] = 
CASE WHEN  [student_Avg] BETWEEN 90 AND 100 THEN 'A'
     WHEN  [student_Avg] BETWEEN 80 AND 89 THEN 'B'
...
END
```

You can be more concise if you avoid checking the upper range at each step (the preceeding case has already done that):

```
UPDATE Student
SET [ student_Grade] = 
CASE WHEN  [student_Avg] > 100 THEN [ student_Grade] /*unexpected value - make no change*/
     WHEN  [student_Avg] >= 90 THEN 'A'
     WHEN  [student_Avg] >= 80 THEN 'B'
...
END
```